# Determine where the function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
>         \frac{(x-1)(y-2)}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)} & \text{for } (x,y)\neq (1,2)\\ (0,0) & \text{for } (x,y)=(1,2)\\
>         \end{array}\right\} $$
>   Determine whereas the function is continuous at $(1,2)$

So we have to see if $lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}f(x,y)=(0,0)$:

$$lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\frac{(x-1)(y-2)}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)}$$

What I have tried:

1. to get rid of $\sin:\sin^2(y-2)\leq (y-2)$ but it will just make the function smaller
2. look at $(x,kx)\rightarrow (1,2)$
3. $-1\leq sin^2(y-2)$

But none have worked? How should I approach it?

Comment: How would you handle $\dfrac{(x-1)(y-2)}{(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer look at $a=(x-1)$ and $b=(y-2)$ to get $lim_{(a,b)\to(0,0)}\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}$ which has no limit? and on $\frac{y-2}{x+1}$ which has not limit too? but this is not sufficent to prove the original function has no limit

Comment: And how do you see that $\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}$ has no limit at $0$? Since $\sin \varphi$ behaves very similarly to $\varphi$ near $0$, it's not unlikely that the same method, perhaps with some fudge factors, would also work for $\frac{ab}{a^2 + \sin^2 b}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer if I take $a=a$ and $b=ka$ I get $\frac{k+1}{1+k^2}$ which is a limit the depends on $k$ so therefore there is not limit

Comment: You get $k\cdot 1$ in the numerator, not $k + 1$. Typo, maybe. Okay. For $\sin$ it isn't quite so nice (though in the limit you get the same), but taking first $k = 0$, and then $k = 1$ suffices. For $k = 0$, you have an immediate limit of $0$ along the $x$-axis. For $k = 1$, you get $\dfrac{a^2}{a^2 + \sin^2 a} = \dfrac{1}{1 + \bigl(\frac{\sin a}{a}\bigr)^2}$, and it's easy to see where that lands.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous at $(1,2)$ then the limit of $f(1+\lambda,2+\lambda)$ when $\lambda\to 0$ should be $f(1,2)=0$. We can easily calculate (via L'H$\hat{\text{o}}$pital's rule or using that $\sin\lambda\approx \lambda$ when $\lambda\approx0$) that this limit is $1/2$ so $f$ can't be continuous at $(1,2)$.